# Docker file with jenkins arficacty copy problem

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Please see the Jenkinsfile and Dockerfile below. I am trying to build and then add my .war file into the docker image that I am creating in jenkins. But it gives me error that `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder785780968/build/libs/demo.war: no such file or directory` . I tested my Dockerfile standalone and it works fine but jenkins cannot find the location of my war. how can I point jenkins where to look?
Thanks.

```
//Dockerfile

FROM tomcat:jdk8-openjdk
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
ADD build/libs/demo.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/. #Fails here due to location of cant find war
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
ENV CATALINA_OPTS "-Xmx512m -Xms256m"
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

//Jenkinsfile

#!groovy

pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage('Build'){
            steps{
                sh "./gradlew --no-daemon build"
            }
        }

        stage('Unit Test'){
          steps{
            sh "./gradlew --no-daemon test"
            }
        }

        stage('Docker Image'){
            agent{
                dockerfile true
            }
            steps{
                echo "docker complete"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the war file exist in the same `slave` in the directory which you have specified  `/build/...`?  Are you missing the forward slash `/build/libs/demo.war`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you mixed two Jenkins pipeline features :

1. customize the Docker execution environment for the Docker agent thanks to a Dockerfile

> Using a Dockerfile
>
> For projects which require a more customized execution environment,
> Pipeline also supports building and running a container from a
> Dockerfile in the source repository. In contrast to the previous
> approach of using an "off-the-shelf" container, using the `agent { dockerfile true }` syntax will build a new image from a Dockerfile
> rather than pulling one from Docker Hub.

2. build a Docker image of your application from a Dockerfile

> Building containers
>
> In order to create a Docker image, the Docker Pipeline plugin also
> provides a build() method for creating a new image, from a Dockerfile
> in the repository, during a Pipeline run.

(Personal note : the `Building containers` title should be  `Building images`)

You want the second one since you copy your built WAR inside the Dockerfile but you have used the first one.

---

Example to build a docker image from a Dockerfile (from the doc):

```
node {
    checkout scm
    def testImage = docker.build("test-image", "./dockerfiles/test") 

    testImage.inside {
        sh 'make test'
    }
}
```

Here it builds a `test-image` image from the Dockerfile found at `./dockerfiles/test/Dockerfile`.
Note that the `docker.build` method returns an object representing the image. Which may be helpful to do things as pushing it into a Docker registry,  copy it on a machine or run it in a next step.

Note that you should now be able to refer [to the built artifact in the previous steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) :

> When Jenkins detects that the agent is itself running inside a Docker
> container, it will automatically pass the --volumes-from argument to
> the inside container, ensuring that it can share a workspace with the
> agent.

A more direct way to build the image with the the current context of pipeline is possible if jenkins was started as a container with as mounted volume the docker socket of the host :

```
stage('Docker Build') {
   agent any
   steps {
     sh 'docker build -f your-dockerfile -t your-tag .'
   }
 }
```